# Custom command - one less than current brightness level

Tags: command-line, brightness

I tried using xbacklight, but it wasnt working so I made some custom global commands to control the brightness. For example:

"Bright" :

```
sudo bash -c "echo 20 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness"
```

"Mid" :

```
sudo bash -c "echo 10 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness"
```

"Dark" :

```
sudo bash -c "echo 0 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness"
```

I want to make two more commands, one that will increase the brightness by one and one that will decrease the brightness by one.

Is there some code I can use in place of 'echo "NUMBER"' that will decrease / increase the current value by one.

I know that the current brightness level *is* the document: /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness which currently reads "20" and changes when using the brightness commands.

I have no idea what this command would be like but something like

```
sudo bash -c "echo [ONE LESS THAN] /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness"
```

I dont know if this is possible, but thanks for any help.

**Update**

What is the correct usage?

When I run "sudo ./brightness.sh +1" it outputs :

```
Usage:
sudo brightness.sh [ + | - | INTEGER ]
./brightness.sh: 10: [: +: unexpected operator
./brightness.sh: 23: [: +: unexpected operator
./brightness.sh: 38: ./brightness.sh: [[: not found
<<< ERROR: wrong parameter 
./brightness.sh: 44: ./brightness.sh: printUsage: not found
```

and when I run "sudo bash brightness.sh +1" it outputs :

```
Usage:
sudo brightness.sh [ + | - | INTEGER ]
brightness.sh: line 27: [: -1: unary operator expected
brightness.sh: line 34: : No such file or directory
```

Comment: Related (or an alternative): http://askubuntu.com/a/672670/72216

Comment: It's not `+1` or `-1`, but either `+`, or `-`, or some number without any sign.

Comment: Hi Carter ! Like muru already told you, the correct usage is `sudo ./brightness.sh +`  or  `sudo ./brightness.sh +`  or `sudo ./brightness.sh 10`.  If you wish , you can change my code to be less confusing or I can do that in my answer .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not make one command  that will increase by one or decrease by one based on the options you pass to it ? That's the basic idea behind the script you will see bellow. We store current value in `CURRENT` variable, then use `bash`'s arithmetic expansion `$(( numberA + numberB ))` to increase or decrease by one. As for decision making, we call the script with single command line argument `+` to increase , or `-` for decrease.

Per muru's suggestion in the comments , I also made a small edit to the code, which now allows you to call `brightness.sh` with an integer parameter less than or equals to the max brightness

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

###########
# Variables
###########
FILE="/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness"
MAX="$(cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/max_brightness)"
MIN=0
CURRENT="$( cat  $FILE )"

###########
# functions
###########

function printUsage
{
  echo "Usage:"
  echo "sudo brightness.sh [ + | - | INTEGER ]"
}

######
# Main
######


if [ $# -eq 0  ];
then
   printUsage
   exit 0
fi


if [ "$1" == "+" ];
then
   NEW=$(( $CURRENT+1  ))
   # are we trying to go past maximum value ? If yes, quit
   if [ $NEW -ge $MAX  ]
   then 
       echo ">>> ERROR: Current value already the maximum; "
       echo ">>> Exiting"
       exit 1
   fi
   # if not, then proceed
   echo "$NEW" > "$FILE"

elif [ "$1" == "-"  ];
then
   NEW=$(( $CURRENT-1  ))
   # Is NEW value going past 0 ? If yes, quit
   if [ $NEW -le $MIN ]; 
   then
       echo ">>> Error: already at minimum. "
       echo ">>> Exiting."
       exit 1
    fi
    # If not, then continue
    echo "$NEW" >  "$FILE"

# Note: new test w/ regex; for portability
# probably better idea to use awk
elif [[ "$1" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] && [ $1 -le $MAX   ];
then
    echo "$1" > "$FILE"

else
    echo "<<< ERROR: wrong parameter "
    printUsage
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: You can probably use a parameter other than `+` or `-` to mean the absolute value of  brightness to be set: `else echo "$1" > "$FILE"; fi`, combining all three use cases.

Comment: @muru added the suggested case, now can use integer parameters

Comment: If you use bash arithmetic test, you can skip the regex test: `(( 10#$1 <= MAX ))`. With the forced use of base 10, only numbers using 0-9 digits should get through.

Comment: @Serg I updated the question, could you please look at that.