# xrandr not working on ubuntu 19.04. How to reduce brightness below default minimum?

Tags: 19.04

The `xrandr` command to reduce brightness below minimum is not working after upgrading Ubuntu to 19.04. How can I reduce the brightness below the default minimum?

Comment: have you tried `xbacklight`?

Comment: See this script: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1150339/increment-brightness-by-value-using-xrandr/1150409#1150409 also make sure you signed into with Xorg and not Wayland.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple step to control brightness in Linux based system

First, you have to know the monitoring screen connected you.

To know this run this command

```
xrandr -q
```

It will give useful information about the screen

[image: screen_info]

( Here my screen connected to eDP, It might be different for your system )

After knowing that run the below command

`xrandr --output eDP --brightness` [0-10]

Replace eDP by your connected screen from the above output and you can have normal brightness values from 0.1 to 1.0

Hope it helps you